# SQL Data By Date in Day and Night Segments

Tags: sql, sql-server

We need to get data for 2 days in Day and Night Segments (the segment times are customer defined). Let's say if customer says from 10/25/2019 8 AM, that means we need to get data for these dates.

```
10/25/2019 8AM - 10/25/2019 8PM (Day DateTime)
10/25/2019 8PM - 10/26/2019 8AM (Night DateTime)
10/26/2019 8AM - 10/26/2019 8PM (Day DateTime)
10/26/2019 8PM - 10/27/2019 8AM (Night DateTime)
```

Now, we pass these dates as XML to a stored procedure and now my question is what is the best way to go over every date row and retrieve the data by columns (Date, Day, Night)? I have thought of implementing a cursor, but is there a better to way to do it?

Comment: Show the sample XML and your desired output from that XML. It is not clear from your question that what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please show us your table schema, sample data and expected result. And please avoid using cursor. it is not the right way for your requirement

Comment: Do you just need to know if any datetime value is "day" or "night" depending on a user defined range for "day"?

Answer (score 0):

> Let's say if customer says from 10/25/2019 8 AM, that means we need to get data for these dates.

Otherwise, your question is rather vague.  You can construct the time periods using a CTE.  Then you can join back to your original data to get counts (or whatever) for the time periods:

```
with cte as (
      select dateadd(hour, v.h1, d.dt) as dt_start,
             dateadd(hour, v.h2, d.dt) as dt_end,
             v.segment
      from (values (convert(datetime, '2019-10-25 8:00:00'))
           ) d(dt) cross join
           (values (0, 12, 'day'),
                   (12, 24, 'night'),
                   (24, 36, 'day'),
                   (36 48, 'night')
           ) v(h1, h2, segment)
     )
select cte.dt_start, cte.dt_end, cte.segment,
       count(t.id)
from t left join
     cte
     on t.dt >= cte.dt_start and
        t.dt < cte.dt_end
group by cte.dt_start, cte.dt_end, cte.segment
order by cte.dt_start;
```

Answer (score 0):

i create you sample data with below query

```
SELECT X,Y
    FROM 
    (
        VALUES 
            ('10/25/2019 8AM','10/25/2019 8PM'),
            ('10/25/2019 8PM','10/26/2019 8AM'),
            ('10/26/2019 8AM','10/26/2019 8PM'),
            ('10/26/2019 8PM','10/27/2019 8AM')
    ) AS F(X , Y)
```

and its output of this query

```
X              Y
-------------- --------------
10/25/2019 8AM 10/25/2019 8PM
10/25/2019 8PM 10/26/2019 8AM
10/26/2019 8AM 10/26/2019 8PM
10/26/2019 8PM 10/27/2019 8AM
```

and write this code over your data

```
SELECT *, 
        CONVERT(DATE,X) AS 'Date' ,
        'DAY & NIGHT' = CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,CONVERT(DATETIME,X)) < 12 THEN 'AM' 
        ELSE 'PM' END
FROM 
(
    SELECT X,Y
    FROM 
    (
        VALUES 
            ('10/25/2019 8AM','10/25/2019 8PM'),
            ('10/25/2019 8PM','10/26/2019 8AM'),
            ('10/26/2019 8AM','10/26/2019 8PM'),
            ('10/26/2019 8PM','10/27/2019 8AM')
    ) AS F(X , Y)
) AS T
```

and its the output of my query

```
X              Y              Date       DAY & NIGHT
-------------- -------------- ---------- -----------
10/25/2019 8AM 10/25/2019 8PM 2019-10-25 AM
10/25/2019 8PM 10/26/2019 8AM 2019-10-25 PM
10/26/2019 8AM 10/26/2019 8PM 2019-10-26 AM
10/26/2019 8PM 10/27/2019 8AM 2019-10-26 PM
```

**NOTE**

your date structure is wrong and you will be convert per row for your data if you convert base data as datetime you give a better performance and dont want the convert to datetime in case statement

**NOTE**
when you convert data as datetime the sql server give 24 structure time then before 12 is AM  and after that is PM